# Split a large dataframe into a list of data frames based on common value in column

Tags: r, performance, matrix, split, dataframe

I have a data frame with 10 columns, collecting actions of "users", where one of the columns contains an ID (not unique, identifying user)(column 10). the length of the data frame is about 750000 rows. I am trying to extract individual data frames (so getting a list or vector of data frames) split by the column containing the "user" identifier, to isolate the actions of a single actor.

```
ID | Data1 | Data2 | ... | UserID
1  | aaa   | bbb   | ... | u_001
2  | aab   | bb2   | ... | u_001
3  | aac   | bb3   | ... | u_001
4  | aad   | bb4   | ... | u_002
```

resulting into

```
list(
ID | Data1 | Data2 | ... | UserID
1  | aaa   | bbb   | ... | u_001
2  | aab   | bb2   | ... | u_001
3  | aac   | bb3   | ... | u_001
,
4  | aad   | bb4   | ... | u_002
...)
```

The following works very well for me on a small sample (1000 rows):

```
paths = by(smallsampleMat, smallsampleMat[,"userID"], function(x) x)
```

and then accessing the element I want by paths[1] for instance.

When applying on the original large data frame or even a matrix representation, this chokes my machine ( 4GB RAM, MacOSX 10.6, R 2.15) and never completes (I know that a newer R version exists, but I believe this is not the main problem).

It seems that split is more performant and after a long time completes, but I do not know ( inferior R knowledge) how to piece the resulting list of vectors into a vector of matrices.

```
path = split(smallsampleMat, smallsampleMat[,10])
```

I have considered also using `big.matrix` etc, but without much success that would speed up the process.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can just as easily access each element in the list using e.g. `path[[1]]`. You can't put a set of matrices into an atomic vector and access each element. A matrix is an atomic vector with dimension attributes. I would use the list structure returned by `split`, it's what it was designed for. Each list element can hold data of different types and sizes so it's very versatile and you can use `*apply` functions to further operate on each element in the list. Example below.

```
#  For reproducibile data
set.seed(1)

#  Make some data
userid <- rep(1:2,times=4)
data1 <- replicate(8 , paste( sample(letters , 3 ) , collapse = "" ) )
data2 <- sample(10,8)
df <- data.frame( userid , data1 , data2 )

#  Split on userid
out <- split( df , f = df$userid )
#$`1`
#  userid data1 data2
#1      1   gjn     3
#3      1   yqp     1
#5      1   rjs     6
#7      1   jtw     5

#$`2`
#  userid data1 data2
#2      2   xfv     4
#4      2   bfe    10
#6      2   mrx     2
#8      2   fqd     9
```

Access each element using the `[[` operator like this:

```
out[[1]]
#  userid data1 data2
#1      1   gjn     3
#3      1   yqp     1
#5      1   rjs     6
#7      1   jtw     5
```

Or use an `*apply` function to do further operations on each list element. For instance, to take the mean of the `data2` column you could use sapply like this:

```
sapply( out , function(x) mean( x$data2 ) )
#   1    2 
#3.75 6.25
```

Comment: I was wondering the performance of `dlply(df, .(userid))` and found that it is bad compared to `split` even without involving the run time of `require(plyr)`, thank you and OP!

Answer (score 41):

From version 0.8.0, `dplyr` offers a handy function called `group_split()`:

```
# On sample data from @Aus_10

df %>%
  group_split(g)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 25 x 3
   ran_data1 ran_data2 g    
       <dbl>     <dbl> <fct>
 1     2.04      0.627 A    
 2     0.530    -0.703 A    
 3    -0.475     0.541 A    
 4     1.20     -0.565 A    
 5    -0.380    -0.126 A    
 6     1.25     -1.69  A    
 7    -0.153    -1.02  A    
 8     1.52     -0.520 A    
 9     0.905    -0.976 A    
10     0.517    -0.535 A    
# … with 15 more rows

[[2]]
# A tibble: 25 x 3
   ran_data1 ran_data2 g    
       <dbl>     <dbl> <fct>
 1     1.61      0.858 B    
 2     1.05     -1.25  B    
 3    -0.440    -0.506 B    
 4    -1.17      1.81  B    
 5     1.47     -1.60  B    
 6    -0.682    -0.726 B    
 7    -2.21      0.282 B    
 8    -0.499     0.591 B    
 9     0.711    -1.21  B    
10     0.705     0.960 B    
# … with 15 more rows
```

To not include the grouping column:

```
df %>%
 group_split(g, keep = FALSE)
```

Comment: Is there a way to have name the list using the dropped grouping column?  I know I can do this: but was wondering if there is a way to do it within dplyr ?names(f.vars.h1.list)<- unique(f.vars.to.agg.1h$ActivityGroup)

Comment: @d3hero23, purrr has a `set_names()` method that applies to lists. But note that group_split provides the output in alphabetical order, so in the example above, you can use `df %>% group_split(g) %>% set_names(df$g %>% unique %>% sort)`

Answer (score 14):

Stumbled across this answer and I actually wanted BOTH groups (data containing that one user and data containing everything but that one user). Not necessary for the specifics of this post, but I thought I would add in case someone was googling the same issue as me.

```
df <- data.frame(
     ran_data1=rnorm(125),
     ran_data2=rnorm(125),
     g=rep(factor(LETTERS[1:5]), 25)
 )

test_x = split(df,df$g)[['A']]
test_y = split(df,df$g!='A')[['TRUE']]
```

Here's what it looks like:

```
head(test_x)
            x          y g
1   1.1362198  1.2969541 A
6   0.5510307 -0.2512449 A
11  0.0321679  0.2358821 A
16  0.4734277 -1.2889081 A
21 -1.2686151  0.2524744 A

> head(test_y)
            x          y g
2 -2.23477293  1.1514810 B
3 -0.46958938 -1.7434205 C
4  0.07365603  0.1111419 D
5 -1.08758355  0.4727281 E
7  0.28448637 -1.5124336 B
8  1.24117504  0.4928257 C
```