# how to generate a series of data frame using loops in R

Tags: r, dataframe

In R how to use a for loop to create a series of data frame? Just for illustration purpose, if need to keep all setosa species of iris data frame to df_setosa, all versicolor in df_versicolor, how to do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a large dataframe into a list of data frames based on common value in column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527051/split-a-large-dataframe-into-a-list-of-data-frames-based-on-common-value-in-colu)

Comment: Why would you want to do so? If you have data of the same structure it's almost always better to keep the data in one data frame.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split` which will will give you a list with your dataframes.

Comment: Thank you.  i could only come up with a simple example, actually what i want to do is to pass each category into a series of operations then output as a data frame of that category. in that case, split won't be enough, how can I output multiple data frame via for loop?

Comment: @santoku Do you want to apply similar operations on each chunk? Appears to me as a use case for `lapply()` and/or grouping using `data.table` or `dplyr`.